# Rails styles persisting between pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks-5

I'm creating a book-reading app. Every book `has_many` pages. I have links going from one page to the next by clicking on the left and right halves of the pages. When you hover over the edge of the page, a div (acting as a link) floating over the page changes its opacity as an indicator that there is another page. These divs are `img-prev` and `img-next`

Here's an example of the hover effect on the right-half of the page:
[image: Example of the hover effect]

The problem is that after clicking to the next (or previous) page, the opacity of the subsequent `img-prev` or `img-next` div for that new page is *very briefly* still its "dark" color, before changing back to fully transparent. I have a feeling this has to do with turbolinks, but I am not sure.

**app/views/pages/show.html.erb**

```rb
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pages' %>

    <div id="div-image-wrapper">
      <% if @page.picture.attached? %>

        <% if @page.previous_page.present? %>
          <%= link_to @page.previous_page do %>
            <div id="img-prev"></div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <%= image_tag @page.picture, class: "img-fluid", id: "img-page" %>

        <% if @page.next_page.present? %>
          <%= link_to @page.next_page do %>
            <div id="img-next"></div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/pages.scss**

```css
    #container-main {
      max-width: 100vw;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #div-image-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #img-prev {
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.0;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    #img-next {
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.0;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    #img-page {
      max-height: 80vh;
    }
```

**app/assets/javascripts/pages.js**

```js
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        if ($('#img-prev').length) {
            $('#img-prev').hover(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.3);
            }, function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0);
            });
        }

        if ($('#img-next').length) {
            $('#img-next').hover(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.3);
            }, function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0);
            });
        }
    });
```

The only clue I have is that if I force my `img-prev` and `img-next` links to ignore turbolinks, the problem goes away, but a full page refresh is done on every page which is less than ideal. The code for that looks like this:

**app/views/pages/show.html.erb (alternate)**

```rb
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pages' %>

    <div id="div-image-wrapper">
      <% if @page.picture.attached? %>

        <% if @page.previous_page.present? %>
          <%= link_to @page.previous_page, "data-turbolinks": false do %>
            <div id="img-prev"></div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <%= image_tag @page.picture, class: "img-fluid", id: "img-page" %>

        <% if @page.next_page.present? %>
          <%= link_to @page.next_page, "data-turbolinks": false do %>
            <div id="img-next"></div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Not sure if it is relevant, but I should mention I have this line added to my **config/initializers/assets.rb**:

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( pages.css )
```

Also, the full sourcecode of this application can be found here on my Github:
https://github.com/tliss/lianhuanhua

Comment: Just a thought, what about manually removing the dark style through JS when the button is clicked and before the request goes through, then when the next page loads add the dark style back? There's always the option to make this a single page app but it's worth a shot to redeem your code anyway, especially if it's such a minor issue

Comment: @maxpleaner I was considering that, but was also just trying to figure out why the style would persist for a split-second on the new page before changing. Is there a particular way that would be best to remove the style? I tried doing $('img-prev').click but I think I didn't construct it right or put it in the right spot.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking like an "on click handler" which there are innumerable tutorials about

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following two files to have the opacity reset after clicking the link and it solved the problem without forcing a full-page refresh. It required adding ids to the  tags:

**app/assets/javascripts/pages.js**

```js
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        if ($('#img-prev').length) {
            $('#img-prev').hover(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.3);
            }, function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0);
            });
        }

        if ($('#img-next').length) {
            $('#img-next').hover(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0.3);
            }, function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 0);
            });
        }

        $('#img-next-link').click(function(){
            $('#img-next-link').css('opacity', 0);
            $('#img-prev-link').css('opacity', 0);
        });

        $('#img-prev-link').click(function(){
            $('#img-next-link').css('opacity', 0);
            $('#img-prev-link').css('opacity', 0);
        });
    });
```

**app/views/pages/show.html.erb**

```rb
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pages' %>

    <div id="div-image-wrapper">
      <% if @page.picture.attached? %>

        <% if @page.previous_page.present? %>
          <%= link_to @page.previous_page, id: "img-prev-link" do %>
            <div id="img-prev"></div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

        <%= image_tag @page.picture, class: "img-fluid", id: "img-page" %>

        <% if @page.next_page.present? %>
          <%= link_to @page.next_page, id: "img-next-link" do %>
            <div id="img-next"></div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </div>
```